# Hair particles don't follow armature deformed mesh

Tags: animation, particles, armature, hair

I have a mesh with a hair particle modifier on it along with an armature that is animated using the Wiggly Bones plugin.

However, when running the animation, the hair kind of 'detaches' from the mesh, and don't follow the deformation nor rotate or do... well, really anything. They kind of flow up and down but all at once and never moving around either.

I have already checked that the particle modifier comes after the armature modifier, as pretty much every other thread about this problem on the internet suggests.

[image]

If I turn off Hair Dynamics, then the particles will follow the mesh deformation fine, but of course do not animation at all. It's when Hair Dynamics is turned on is when this weird behavior starts.

[image]

I have also tried (and tried and tried) running Bake All Dynamics under the cache tab with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Frame 1:

[image]

Frame 17:

[image]

Frame 23:

[image]

and so on.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is a bug, actually. Would it make sense to submit it on the tracker?